# Mongodb aggregate Exclude All Fields at a Given Level and given nodename

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this

```
{
  Activities:[{
    Watchers:{
    Name1:{
      Read:1,
      View:2
    },
    Name2:{
      Read:3,
      View:4}
    }}]
}
```

For a given user(name1 or name2). I only want to return that users information. How do I do this from mongo aggregate operation?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking here. But if you are naming the 
"keys" individually then you should not be doing that. MongoDB is still a database afterall. Don't change names of keys, but change the data properties of standard keys instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The users list could be very big, we thought this way mongo will hash the name, so we don't have to create an index on name. Is that the right way? Even if we are using array, how do we limit the user from aggregate operation?

Comment: Completely the wrong way. Whilst Wired Tiger storage does offer some "compactness" on field name properties this does not help and actually hinders search of data enormously. What you want is the data to be indexed for speed. If you have varying keys then aggregate cannot help you as it cannot traverse keys. If you just want single user matches then you should just be able to do in queries, and quickly if you structure correctly. Right now an array with a single entry of items with different keys does not make the intention clear. Except that it will cause you problems.

Comment: ok, so it I changed it array of object, with username as key for each object, how do I filter other users out from aggregate operation?